# Unable to return ref point using linkConnectionPoint function

Tags: jointjs

I created a **rect** element with **magnet** property set to **true**. When I try to connect a link to the element, it gets connected to a point on the perimeter of the rectangle.

Then, I tried using **linkConnectionPoint** function as defined in the following code snippet:

[linkConnectionPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUTF7.png)

But, the function is not been executed anytime I create a new link.

Is there any issue in the way of defining the function?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please read source code.
https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/src/joint.dia.link.js#L1250

if joint.dia.Paper.perpendicularLinks is true, then never use linkConnectionPoint option...
so, please set 'perpendicularLinks' to false.